# Javascript: How to capture `DOMException: Aborted` from AbortController in an IF statement?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, abort

I'm using an `AbortController` and catching the error it throws when it aborts. My debugger says that the error is `DOMException: Aborted`. I want to capture that in an IF statement, but I'm not sure how. I tried `if (e == "DOMException: Aborted")` and `if (e == "Aborted")` but they don't capture it.

My code:

```
  controller = new AbortController();
  const signal = controller.signal;
  fetch(url, { signal })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log('Download complete', response);
    })
    .catch(function(e) {
      console.log('Download error: ' + e.message);
    });
```

then I abort this controller with `controller.abort()`

Comment: can you share your code please ?

Comment: @sohaiebazaiez I edited my original post to include my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a `DOMException` instance, an object not a string. The proper condition to test for it is

```
.catch(function(e) {
  if (e instanceof DOMException && e.name == "AbortError") {
    // …
  } else {
    console.log('Download error: ' + e.message);
  }
});
```

You can also check whether `e.code == DOMException.ABORT_ERR`.

Comment: Please note that `e.code == DOMException.ABORT_ERR` is deprecated.